ROS navigation RobotModel Status:Error
0
I'm trying to do navigation in ROS, when i run navigation there are several errors like No transform from base_scan to map. Other errors are all about transform to map. when i checked the tf tree, there are map->odom->base_footprint->base_link-> laser and imu_link. I add robot_description param to solve the [parameter [robot_description] does not exist and was not found by searchparam] error. I also have files that have robot value like wheel_left, but I don't know what is the reason of this error. can anyone tell me the reason of this problem and solution?

